# Error when referring .Net Standard project in Xamarin Android Project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, .net-standard

I'm getting this error when I add a reference to the .Net Standard project in the Andoid Project.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Can not resolve reference: `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions`,
>   referenced by `DotNetty.Transport`. Please add a NuGet package or
>   assembly reference for `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions`, or remove
>   the reference to `DotNetty.Transport`.    VFMApp.Droid

I tried:

1. Neither NuGet packages (System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions / DotNetty.Transport), clean solution, compiled project successfully, reference project, compile: ERROR
2. NuGet package for DotNetty.Transport, clean solution, compiled project successfully, reference project, compile: ERROR
3. NuGet package for System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, clean solution, compile project successfully, reference project, compile: ERROR
4. Both NuGet packages (System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions / DotNetty.Transport), clean solution, compile project successfully, reference project, compile: ERROR

Packages in .Net Standard project:

- Acr.UserDialogs 7.0.1
- Humanizer 2.5.16
- Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client 1.18.1
- Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client 4.1.1
- Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.Client.SQLiteStore 4.1.1
- NETStandard.Library 2.0.3
- Plugin.Share 7.1.1
- Refractored.MvvmHelpers 1.4.1-beta
- Xam.Plugin.Connectivity 4.0.0.190-beta
- Xam.Plugin.DeviceInfo 4.1.0-beta
- Xam.Plugin.Geolocator 4.5.4-beta
- Xam.Plugin.Media 4.1.1-beta
- Xam.Plugins.Settings 4.0.0.10-beta

Packages in Android project:

- Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat 28.0.0
- Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 28.0.0
- Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Maps 60.1142.1

Comment: Why does your NetStd library have native Android packages in it?

Comment: @SushiHangover for this like:

        public virtual async Task<bool> SyncAsync()
        {
            if (!CrossConnectivity.Current.IsConnected)
            {
                Logger.Instance.Track("Unable to sync items, we are offline");
                return false;
            }
            try

CrossConnectivity being from a xam package. This is actually Microsoft's code. I'm trying to do my version of https://github.com/Azure-Samples/MyDriving, and failing, with newer packages, simpler architecture, etc.

Comment: ? I just look at their PCL library and it does not contain Android packages and neither should yours, not really sure how you got them to install/restore properly

Comment: I think they do: https://ibb.co/7grMYFs

Comment: I think not ;-) https://github.com/Azure-Samples/MyDriving/blob/master/src/MobileApps/MyDriving/MyDriving/packages.config

Comment: In my comment, I talked about the XAM packages. The Xamarin packages were just a typo, as I double enter the references in the Android project.

In any case, your comment doesn't address the original question.

Comment: Are you seeing this issue on VS for Mac or VS for Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get the same error as you when I referenced DotNetty.Transport from a Xamarin.Android project compiling/targeting against API Level 28.  It seems to be an issue with [System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions/) v4.5.1 that [DotNetty.Transport](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetty.Transport/) is referencing.  Here is a link to a similar problem from another project:

https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/issues/803

To sum up the issue, it looks like that `Systems.Threading.Tasks.Extensions` v4.5.1 has an empty profile for MonoAndroid10.  Because the profile is empty, it can not resolve the `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll` file, thus the error.

[image]

To fix this, you have to update your android *.csproj file and redirect the reference to use the `System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll` that is defined in the `netstandard2.0` profile.

[image]

I performed the following steps:

1. Add the System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions v4.5.1 nuget package to your Xamarin.Android project.
2. Add the System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe v4.5.2 nuget package to your Xamarin.Android project
3. Close Visual Studio.
4. Open your Xamarin.Android *.csproj file with a Text Editor.
5. Add another `<ItemGroup>` to tell your project to use the `.netstandard2.0` profile instead of the `MonoAndroid10` profile

```html
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions">
        <HintPath>$(UserProfile)\.nuget\packages\system.threading.tasks.extensions\4.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
</ItemGroup>
```

So it should look something like this:

[image]

Save the file and reload your project in visual studio.  After I did that I was able to compile successfully.